# Problem with running JavaME

Tags: java-me, emulation

I'm getting angry - I cant run the emulator (under vista x64).

I still get the following error:

`Starting emulator in execution mode
* Error *
Failed to connect to device 2!
Reason:
Emulator 2 terminated while waiting for it to register!
BUILD FAILED (total time: 26 seconds)`

I was trying to change the port to 1999, localhost to ip address and such stuff. Do you have any ideas what to do?

Thank you in advance!

Cheers

Comment: Is this error from Java ME SDK 3.0?

Comment: the emulator and wtk only run on 32bit os

Comment: Are you sure? I have tried on the Virtual Machine with 32bit OS with no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this problem. I managed to solve it for NetBeans 6.8. (I still use it, and recommend it)

Since version 6.8 (or maybe earlier), NetBeans is bundled with Java ME SDK of [version 3.0](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30.jsp). But in my opinion, [version 2.5.2_01](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/download.html) is much better. You should [download](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/download.html) and install it, then add it as Java ME platform in NetBeans.